# Android dialog dim animation

Tags: android

Long story short: how to set the duration of dim animation which occurs when showing a dialog?

Dim opacity can be controlled via `getWindow().getAttributes().dimAmount`, but I couldn't find anything related to the animation duration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll have to answer myself. I've looked into Android sources only to find out it's impossible.

On Android < 3.0 the animation duration is hardcoded and it's set to 1200ms.
On Android >= 3.0, the animation duration is equal to the duration of window enter/exit animation.

Comment: Hi. Did you set the animation on a Dialog theme with `android:windowAnimationStyle` attribute or on activity?